# Admin cannot see permission access

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am an admin in a SharePoint site. I am trying to clean up permissions. On one page, the 'permissions' link is greyed-out for me.

Could you let me know why this could be?

This is also true with a library called 'Documents', I could not see 'Permissions' under 'Library Settings' (other libraries have this link)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you the site collection administrator or site owner?  If you don't see Permissions Link under Library Setting it seems that you don't have correct permissions